# Android Camera api using Webrtc affect record video button not working

Tags: android, camera, webrtc

My app using camera2 api using webrtc video call affect that the native camera app on 6.0.1 gets dimmed out(not clickable) record video button.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to call `Camera.release()` after your app is finished/done.